# Cannot fetch timestamp value in mysql into time.Time variable

Tags: mysql, go, timestamp

I cannot get mysql timestamp value in into a time.Time variable

I am trying to scan a row, All values get successfully scanned except the timestamp type in mysql, I am already using dsn parseTime=true which was one of the issues i searched into, but it does not help

```
        type Tags struct {
            ID             int
            CreatedAt      time.Time `json:"created_at"`
        }
        func foo5() {
            http.HandleFunc("/tags/", bar5)
            http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
        }

        func bar5(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:*******@/catalogue_service?parseTime=true")
            if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("error opening")
            }
            v, _ := strconv.Atoi(path.Base(r.URL.Path))
            row := db.QueryRow("select * from tags where id = ?", v)
            var myRow Tags
            row.Scan(&myRow.ID, &myRow.CreatedAt)
            fmt.Println(myRow)
        }
```

int and string values are displayed properly but CreatedAt prints
   0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
instead of the actual value

Edit:

```
 +-----------------+--------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| Field           | Type                     | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                                         |
+-----------------+--------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| id              | int(11)                  | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment                                |
| created_at      | timestamp                | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | DEFAULT_GENERATED                             |
+-----------------+--------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------+

| 84 | 2019-01-30 11:21:36 |
```

Comment: What is the data type of created_at in your mysql table and what is the format(RFC 3339 ?) in which it is stored?

Comment: this was the result from describe tags for created_at

Comment: Share one timestamp how it is stored in db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error has been resolved by myself,
there were null values in the table which Scan could not handle hence i used sql.NULLString or mysql.NULLTime type in struct depending on the field

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered the mysql driver as follows ?

```
import _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
```

See the usage here:

https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#usage

https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#timetime-support

Comment: Yes absolutely, i checked out the links they only mention date, datetime not timestamp